# Is it possible / practical to convert a 3d line segment to a point in 2d so that I can easily measure points from it's origin?

Tags: matrix, geometry, trigonometry, projection, algebra

Consider the following scenario:

[image: desired plane conversion]

I have a line segment in 3d to track an ideal approach to a given runway.  Aircraft's objective is to try to fly ON this particular line into the touchdown zone, however, no one is perfect, and players will inevitably fly too high, too low, to far to the left, or too far to the right of this line.

My goal is to identify if a player is too high, too low, too too far to the left, or too far to the right.  and do something if the player is too far in any given side (this includes printing to the player that they're too high or too low).

The question:
(Considering the above illustration:) If I have a given a cartesian line segment in 3d space (line = x, y, z && line2 = x1, y1, z1) and a player's point relative to the line (also in 3d space), does it make sense / is it practical to convert the 3d line to a singular point on its own axis (origin 0, 0) and measure the distance to the player's point relative to the origin?
If so, how could I approach converting this 3d line in a fixed dimension to a point in a separate dimension.

My thought process:
Every 2d line can be represented as a point in 1d so long as we're looking down the line.  If we do this and make that point the origin of a 2d grid, measuring relative distance becomes easy.

I think it's possible to also use other methods / approaches such as cross products, but if this is cheaper, I'd prefer to use this method.

Anyways, I'd love to hear your feedback.  Please let me know what you think!
Note: I'm using lua

I've seen some mentions of homogenous coordinates, but I've noticed that because the axis is fixed despite a desired rotated axis, it causes issues in various conditions.
Measuring a distance to closest point on the line is simple, but not so much when trying to identify if it's left or right / up or down relative to the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **create basis vectors `X` right,`Y` up**

   you can use local ground normal `n`, line `(p0,p1)` direction and cross product to do this

   ```
   X = cross( n , p1-p0 );
   Y = cross( n , X ); Y /= |Y|;
   X = cross( Y , n ); X /= |X|;
   ```
2. **convert**

   ```
   x = dot( p-p0 , X )
   y = dot( p-p0 , Y )
   ```

   now `x,y` is signed distance from your line aligned to your wanted directions...

[edit1] moved from comments...

Anyway if you want signed scalar distance `d` along some unit vector `v` from some starting point `p0` of some point `p` then it is:

```
d = dot(v,p-p0);
```

now you just provide vector `v` along whatever you want to measure the distance. As your ground is plane `z=0` using parametric circle equation (using `azimuth` as parameter) you get vector along your runway

```
(cos(azimuth),sin(azimuth),0)
```

if you want the vector left/right you just rotate it by 90 deg so either use `azimuth + PI/2` or swap `x,y` and negate one for example

```
(-sin(azimuth),cos(azimuth),0)
```

if you want up vector its just `(0,0,1)`

From what you describe now you want axis `Y` to be perpendicular to your approach line `(p0,p1)` and point up (angled) so you can exploit cross product which will return perpendicular vector to its operands so:

```
Y = cross(p1-p0,cross(p1-p0,(0,0,1))); Y/=length(Y);
```

the internal cross `cross(p1-p0,(0,0,1))` will be the same as `X` if the approach line is aligned to your runway...

Comment: This makes sense...well a little bit - A few questions:


1. Getting the cross product is easy enough, but how do I get the normal?  Is this based on a rotation of choice? How is it formatted, and how would I be able to use it in an equation like the above?


2. I notice there's a semicolon.  Is this to distinguish a separate part of the equation or a synonymous one? 


3.  What do the pipes | Y | around each vector represent?  Normalization? How is this processed?


4. On the dot product, is 'p' supposed to represent 'p1'?

Sorry for my ignorance, but this is somewhat new to me.

Comment: @Wetter42 1. Normal is 3D vector You can use local position ground  plane normal (not sure if you have WGS84 or just planar Earth but in both cases you should know the normal coordinates for example `(0,0,1)`) You can also obtain it from your runway mesh. 2. semicolon means end of line of code in C/C++ like languages so you can have more stuff in single text line 3. `|a|` means absolute value of vector (its length) see [edit2 in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) 4. `p` is your plane position and `p0,p1` are the runway ideal approach line endpoints all 3D vectors ...

Comment: It is planar earth.  and the coordinates are z-up, x-north, and y-west.
Does this mean that my ground normal is simply (0, 0, 1)? Since it's 1 unit perpendicular to the planar ground (spanning the x / y axis)?

Also, for the C / C++ stuff;  It makes sense BUT I'm curious;  After we get the cross product, we get the result of Y, but we still have work to do by taking y and making it equal to Y / |Y| (abs value / length of 'Y'), correct?  

After we perform the division is that the FINAL result of Y?

Lastly, P is plane as in Airplane! I see that now! not plane (planar)
That makes sense!

Comment: Plugging in what I think are the variables, I get the following:      

X = cross( n , p1-p0 );
n = (0, 0, 1)
p1 - p0 = (3484.432, -2011.506, -470.001)

Since the X and Y values are 0, running the cross product will return a total value of 0, 0, 0
The same for dot product of Y and X;  

It just doesn't make sense to me...then we divide 0 by the length of 0?  I know I'm missing something!

Comment: @Wetter42 yes normal is `0,0,1` in such case and `Y=Y/|Y|` is just normalization to unit size ... cross product between 2 vectors returns vector that is perpendicular to both... Your `cross ( (0, 0, 1) , (3484.432, -2011.506, -470.001)  )` should be non zero (unless the 2 vectors are parallel but that is not the case) so your cross product computation is wrong see the [edit2 in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214). I use `p` name usually for points (but in this case the point in question is also the airplane)

Comment: Gotcha - Yes, that makes sense, and you're right - my calculation was just wrong;  I'll mark your answer as a solution - Just one more question though.  
after running the cross product, I end up with a 3d vector.  When getting the unit length (y = y / |y| aka Y/=|Y|, does this mean I'm dividing each value within the vector 3 by the absolute value? 

If so, I end up with a final Y as: 
(-1, 1, 0)

Is that correct? / does that sound correct?

Sorry, and thanks for the clarification! :D

Comment: @Wetter42 yes `Y=Y/|Y|` means you divide each coordinate of `Y` by the length of `|Y|` but no the result can not be `(-1,1,0)` more like `(-0.707,0.707,0)` because the result will be unit vector (so `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1.0` ) ... I think you should read some vector math/algebra tutorial or book as its crucial for 3D programming (yes you can live without it but using it will make your life muuuuuuuuuuch easier) the same goes for linear algebra (matrices)

Comment: My bad - when you said absolute value of it's length, I took that as absolute value;

Also, I am in fact reading  [this book](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics-for-computer-graphics/geometry/how-does-matrix-work-part-1.html) but they mention length denoted as ||Y|| instead of |Y| in which the square root of (vx * vx + vy * vy + vz * vz)

Not sure if that was the equation you were referring to, but it's confusing finding a north star of truth when approaching two different resources of a subject.  Thanks for your help buddy! :D

Comment: @Wetter42 Yes I am from east/central Europe (former COMECON) and we used common terminology and markings which is not the case for western world (especially  english math and physics) there it is usually inconsistent and the equation form and meaning changes with field its used in or even country to country ... also the `||y||` might be just because `|` character was not available at the time it was started using on computers for math equations... or someone just wanted to differ between scalar and vector absolute value ...

Comment: okay this works reallly well...but only for the approach line's X axis.  For some reason, the signed distance measured isn't measured along the Z axis like I was hoping it would.

Take a look at the runway touchdown zone [here](https://imgur.com/a/bvQDkCl) - Notice how the x (blue) and y (purple) axis follow the ground and not the line.  

My idea was to have the purple line measuring the normalized distance from the line.  (e.g. when flying above the line, or below, you're x meters).  

For x, it performs as expected as left / right deviations from center increase the value....

Comment: ....HOWEVER, for y, when increasing my players position towards the P0, it seems that it's not following the line but rather, the point in which the line begins (diagram).

Hope that's not as messy as it seems to me...LOL

Comment: Eeh, it's actually supposed to be the linear distance along the line itself and not the runway;  E.g. Close your eyes and pretend you're looking directly down the center of the line.  X axis is left and right of the dot, Y axis is above and below the dot.  Z axis doesn't exist (as it's passing through origin and being ignored).  
Note: The purple axis (side to side) works like a charm as it measures how centered you are.  However, the blue line measures that particular point on the runway which is what I don't want.  I want it to measure my point along the line (my y axis).  Hope this helps!

Comment: nonetheless, your azimut equation looks promising....I'll take a look! :D

Comment: Okay, and Y=(cos(azmimuth), sin(azimuth), 0, 0);  Is the Y azimuth different from the X azimuth?

E.g. that's just rotation along the x / y axis respectively, correct?

Comment: You know what? Scratch this - I think I'm going about the rest of this equation wrong - Here's my question:
Considering the "X" component of the original question was correct, but the "Y" component was along the ground axis rather than the axis normal to the line, is there any quick way to mathematically rotate the Y axis such that it measures relative distance from the line? 

Alternatively, are there any short modifications to the original equation that allow us to do the same thing: That is rotate the Y axis so that it's measuring the distance along the line and NOT the point P0?

Comment: Again, thanks for your patience.

Comment: Okay, well, believe it or not, that's what I was trying to explain the entire time.  THIS FREAKING DID IT MAN, THANK YOU! Can I message you - I want to say thank you!

Comment: @Wetter42 I moved the important stuff to my answer (edit1) and removed obsolete comments (you can do the same)... what do you mean by message me if you write comment to any of my posts or any post where I have a comment and add `@my_nick` to the comment the site will notify me automatically ...